# When trying to import Matplotlib.pyplot, get "UnicodeDecodeError"

Tags: python, matplotlib

When trying to run a Python script starting with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/Documents/Python/tax_rates.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 62, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1421, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1406, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1044, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 324, in findSystemFonts
    for f in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 276, in get_fontconfig_fonts
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1340, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried re-installing both Python and Matplotlib using the commands

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-matplotlib
```

but to no avail. How can I get Pyplot to import correctly?

Comment: Try this: `import sys`  `reload(sys)` `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` at the start of your program. (On separate lines, obviously.)

Comment: Silly question, but how did you create the script exactly?

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide the code for `tax_rates.py` in a pastebin.

Comment: Hmm, I think it may be related to the font cache instead of `tax_rates.py`.  Can you clear your font cache as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771191/matplotlib-taking-time-when-being-imported and try running `tax_rates.py` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I've tried Jos' suggestion of adding the following lines to the beginning of `tax_rates.py`:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

I was happy to see that the script now does run and produces a plot (see below a screenshot from Atom editor).

[image]

I would welcome a more 'permanent' solution, though.

P.S. For your reference, the entire `tax_rates.py` script is copied below.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# income = np.linspace(0,2e6,2001)

thresholds = np.array([0, 9725, 37650, 190150, 413350, 415050])

print(thresholds)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(thresholds,thresholds)
plt.show()
```

Comment: By the way, I notice that if I run "python tax_rates.py" from the command line, I get simply the desired printed output and plot without any warnings as seen in the Atom Runner (which runs by pressing "Alt+R" in Atom). So in the command line the problem appears to be entirely fixed by Jos' suggestion.

Comment: The question is still open: how did you exactly create it? Which editor? etc.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a recommended method: https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/.

Comment: A more permanent solution would be that `subprocess.py` does not crash on a non-UTF8 input (which is what I assume happens). Perhaps this should be reported as a bug.